# Removing features from the attribute table that were deleted from the map via vector overlay

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, clip

I am trying to do some mapping of precinct level voter analysis in new US districts. In order to do so, I have precincts overlay the district shape, and then I clip so the precincts match the district shape. However, even though the precincts are clipped in the same shape, I can still see labels of other precincts immediately outside the boundaries of the new shape. Additionally, the deleted features are still in the attribute table. In this screenshot, the numbers around the edges were deleted features, but the labels still show up in the image and in the attribute table.

Is there a way to remedy this?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Which tool are you using to clip?

Comment: I am using the Clip feature in the vector overlay tools.

Comment: I will try to add a screenshot tomorrow when I am back at my other computer